# Python networking programming through sockets

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I don't know how to make the server to take the command from the user ... I have untill now this code for the server

```
import socket, sys 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
#HOST = sys.argv.pop() if len(sys.argv) == 3 else '127.0.0.1' 
HOST = 'localhost' 
PORT = 8080 
def recv_all(sock, length): 
    data = '' 
    while len(data) < length: 
        more = sock.recv(length - len(data)).decode() 
        if not more: 
            raise EOFError('socket closed %d bytes into a %d-byte message' % 
(len(data), length)) 
        data += more 
    return data 
#if sys.argv[1:] == ['server']: 
if True: 
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
    s.bind((HOST, PORT)) 
    s.listen(1) 
    while True: 
        print('Listening at', s.getsockname()) 
        sc, sockname = s.accept() 
        print('We have accepted a connection from', sockname) 
        print('Socket connects', sc.getsockname(), 'and', sc.getpeername()) 
        message = recv_all(sc, 16) 
        print('The incoming sixteen-octet message says', repr(message)) 
        sc.sendall('Farewell, client'.encode())
```

This is the rest from srver-side and i can't get working it from here , in rest everything works perfect! ....

```
        if repr(message) == 'exit':
            sc.close() 
            print('Reply sent, socket closed') 
    else: 
        print(sys.stderr, 'usage: tcp_local.py server|client [host]')
```

And this code for the client

```
import socket, sys 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
# HOST = sys.argv.pop() if len(sys.argv) == 3 else '127.0.0.1' 
HOST = 'localhost' 
PORT = 8080 
def recv_all(sock, length): 
    data = '' 
    while len(data) < length: 
        more = sock.recv(length - len(data)).decode() 
        if not more: 
            raise EOFError('socket closed %d bytes into a %d-byte   message' 
            % (len(data), length)) 
        data += more 
    return data 

#elif sys.argv[1:] == ['client']: 
if True: 
    print('Connecting to server on: ',HOST,' Port: ',PORT) 
    s.connect((HOST, PORT)) 
    print('Client has been assigned socket name', s.getsockname()) 
    s.sendall('Hi there, server'.encode()) 
    print('Hi there, server, has been send') 
    reply = recv_all(s, 16) 
    print('The server said', repr(reply))
    command = (input('enter:').encode())
    s.sendall(command)
    if s.send(command) == 'exit':
            s.close() 
else: 
    print(sys.stderr, 'usage: tcp_local.py server|client [host]')
```

I can get the client to ask the user for input , and when I enter the string 'exit' (without the quotation marks) in the client side I don't know how to make the server read the raw text and convert it into close server function ... any help would be greatly appreciated ... have a nice Sunday everyone !

I get "Type error : 'str' does not support the buffer interface"

Everythong works fine now , I've added the .encode() at the command = (input('enter:').encode()) part . but how do i make the server to close after this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of what I am saying but for what I know, if you are using python 3.x, you need to convert string to bytes before sending to through an socket. On the client you should do  `command = bytes(input('enter:'), "utf-8")` and on the server you have to put it back as string so, `message = recv_all(sc, 16).decode("utf-8")`. Not tested...